# Como modificar el queryset de un campo ManyToMany en Django Framework

Tags: django, sql

mi pregunta es para saber si se puede y como seria para modificar el QuerySet por defecto que trae un campo con el modelo ManyToMany, pues segun entiendo el query por defecto es:

```
Modelo.objects.all()
```

Pero quisiera cambiar ese queryset por un filtro, se como armar la consulta del filtro pero no se donde o en que parte colocar o modificar el query, es decir no se si va en el ModelAdmin o en los Models.

Answer (score 0):

Sería algo como `Modelo.objects.filter().values('valor1', 'valor2')` o con `Modelo.objects.filter().values_list('valor1', 'valor2')`

Nota:

> Devuelve un QuerySetque devuelve diccionarios, en lugar de instancias de modelo, cuando se usa como iterable. Cada uno de esos diccionarios representa un objeto, con las claves correspondientes a los nombres de atributo de los objetos modelo.
>
> El values_list(): Esto es similar, values() excepto que en lugar de devolver diccionarios, devuelve tuplas cuando se itera. Cada tupla contiene el valor del campo o expresión correspondiente que se pasa a la values_list()llamada, por lo que el primer elemento es el primer campo, etc.